# Android how to make this "wave" like custom design for layout background?

Tags: android, xml, layout

**I need exactly like this showing in the picture with maroon background**
**How I can achieve this.**

[image]

Comment: I know how to create rounded background with rounded corners but this is something different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use this site for make wave svg

https://getwaves.io/

and add to android studio, then use for background image

Comment: nice answer, worked for me.

Comment: this will return svg file convert the picture to png first then add to android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use every picture you want from drawable, and set to your layout

```
android:background="@drawable/my_picture"
```

Comment: Bro I know this but I wanted to know that how to create this wave like background with code.